# What method can be used for this integration

Tags: integration

I have a variable $\theta$ in which its distribution is given as
\begin{equation}
 p_{\theta}(\theta)= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} 
  \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\theta-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{\!2}\,\right)
\end{equation}
with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, I have the integral as follows

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2} \bigg(  1-\sqrt{ \dfrac{a(\cos\theta - \sin\theta)^2}{2+{a(\cos\theta - \sin\theta)^2}}}\times\dfrac{4}{3\pi}
\\
\bigg[\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\tan^{-1} \big(\sqrt{\dfrac{{a(\cos\theta - \sin\theta)^2}}{2+{a(\cos\theta - \sin\theta)^2}}}\cot\dfrac{\pi}{4}\big)\bigg] \bigg) p_{\theta}(\theta) \,\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{split}
\end{equation}
What a method I can use for this integration.

Comment: I doubt $p_\theta(\theta)$ was the notation used, it's bad practice to repeat variables as a denoting a class of functions and a variable at the same time in two different places. Also, this integral may not exist. When $\sin\theta > \cos\theta$, the square roots are imaginary

Comment: Are you certain about the integration bounds?

Comment: thanks Ninad for your comments. I missed the squared. Yes Sal